# How to Call jquery function from server side

Tags: c#, jquery

I have two dynamically created textboxes (txtFrom & txtTo) from server side code. I want to call a jquery function onmouseup event of these textboxes. How can I do the same. My jquery function is given below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtFrom').datepicker({
        //appendText:'mm/dd/yyyy',
        showOn: 'both',
        buttonText: '..',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        //numberOfMonths:2,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: new Date(2017, 4, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(2025, 3, 31)
    });
});
```

Thanking you in anticipation.

The code which is adding the textboxes dynamically is as follows:

```
protected void getDateControls()
{
    foreach (GridViewRow grow in gdView.Rows)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtFrom = new 
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
        txtFrom.ID = "txtFrom";
        txtFrom.Width = 70;
        txtFrom.AutoPostBack = true;
        txtFrom.TextChanged += new 
    System.EventHandler(this.txtFrom_Changed);
        grow.Cells[5].Controls.Add(txtFrom);

        System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtTo = new 
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
        txtTo.ID = "txtTo";
        txtTo.Width = 70;
        enter code heretxtTo.AutoPostBack = true;
    txtTo.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtTo_Changed);
    grow.Cells[6].Controls.Add(txtTo);
    }
}
```

I want the jquery function to be called onclick or onmouseup event of these textboxes.

Comment: So what's the question here? What does the code which you shared? What issues you are facing with this code? What is the expected behavior? Can you share the code which adds textboxes dynamically?

Comment: your questions makes no sense

Comment: Why do you want to call the jquery function from server side? It is possible but you may not need to do this so explain why you want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need use Jquery.on for hooking events for dynamic controls

try the below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click","input[id*='txtFrom']",function(){ //whatever code you want });
    $(document).on("click","input[id*='txtTo']",function(){ //whatever code you want });
});
</script>
```

> Note: if anyone asked to show your code you need to update your
>   question instead of adding an answer. Please remove it.